# The best way to automate test with selenium web driver, to check email from gmail?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, gmail

I would like to know the best way to automate a test with selenium web driver, to validate an email sent by an application.

I've tried to automate, but the "Captcha" validation appears and i cannot pass that screen. I'm using java.

Comment: The answer is don't use webdriver; use the API - https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/.  A browser-based approach will be flaky (at best), have to deal with Captcha (which is trying to prevent exactly what you are trying to do), and is a violation of the TOS.

Comment: Many thanks for your quick response. I'm not an expert in code, so i need to see an example to try to reproduce, do you have a simple example?